# What happens when exception occurs ,while in form closing event

Tags: c#, .net

What happens when exception occurs,while in form closing event.Does the form gets closed or  form remains open.

Comment: generate an exception and test it

Answer (score 0):

Form remains open. Exception will be caught by OnThreadException. And, by default, application will show you message box.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the exception your getting.... Please check below image here a messagebox displayed as exception its asking for "Continue" or "Quit"

[image: Error]